# Logstash date parsing error

Tags: parsing, elasticsearch, grok, logstash

Summary: I have my log with the date format as shown :

```
2013/05/09-05:19:16.772
```

Now I want to use logstash and send these logs to elastic search. But the problem is that I want that the timestamp value should be that of the logs and not the current time.

Therefore, I have written the following. This fails saying this:

```
Invalid format: "2013/05/09-05:19:16.876" is malformed at "/05/09-05:19:16.876", :backtrace=>["org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:866)"
```

My conf file is:

```rb
input {
  stdin {
      type => "stdin-type"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    type => "stdin-type"
    patterns_dir=>["./patterns"]
    pattern => "%{PARSE_ERROR}"
    add_tag=>"%{type1},%{type2},%{slave},ERR_SYSTEM"
  }

  date {
    type => "stdin-type"
    match=>["ts","yyyy/mm/dd-HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
    locale=>"en"
  }

  mutate {
    type=>"stdin-type"
    replace => ["@message", "%{message}" ]
    replace => ["@timestamp", "%{ts}" ]
  }
}

output {
  stdout { debug => true debug_format => "json"}
  elasticsearch { }
}
```

I am really stuck here.
Need some expert help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You have specifed lowercase `m` instead of `M`. `m` is for minutes and `M` is for months.

Try:

```
yyyy/MM/dd-HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

Answer (score 1):

What is not readily apparent from the error until you enable verbose mode (-vv) from the command line is that the 'date' filter [is using the JodaTime library](https://github.com/logstash/logstash/blob/438b85bbbf33c5daf6e64feb6efb5a8ca9e9fa3d/lib/logstash/filters/date.rb#L47). In my case, I was using a regex from a previous step to parse the date and time. This obviously won't work because it's not what JodaTime expects. For the allowable date time formats, you should look at the [DateTimeFormat documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
YYYY/MM/dd-HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

instead